# React .jsx 'ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION'

Tags: reactjs, node.js

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGSIp.png)showing this error in whil running react project

```
react .jsx TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".jsx" for C:\Users\PREDATOR\Desktop\React-Todo\src\App.jsx
    at Object.getFileProtocolModuleFormat [as file:] (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:160:9)
    at defaultGetFormat (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:203:36)
    at defaultLoad (node:internal/modules/esm/load:141:22)
    at async ModuleLoader.load (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:409:7)
    at async ModuleLoader.moduleProvider (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:291:45)
    at async link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:21) {
  code: 'ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION'
Node.js v20.10.0
```

Comment: You don't seem to have set up any process that would allow the JSX files to be parsed to JS. Also, unless you want to do server-side rendering, it seems wrong that you attempt to load a JSX module with node in the first place.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.